# Output being displayed as list when it should be a table

Tags: arrays, powershell

I am trying to get a rather simple script to have a pretty display when I run the script.  I know I am overlooking something simple, but I can't identify exactly what.  What I am using is PowerCLI commands to grab my ESXi hosts and some NIC info, then display it back to me.  The gathering of information works fine, just having trouble displaying it back.

```
$nicinfo = @()

$myHosts = Get-VMHost

foreach ($vmhost in $myHosts) {
    $objInfo = New-Object PSObject
    $esxcli = Get-Esxcli -vmhost $vmhost
    $firmware = $esxcli.network.nic.get('vmnic0')
    $driverName = $firmware.DriverInfo.Driver
    $fwversion = $firmware.DriverInfo.FirmwareVersion
    $drversion = $firmware.DriverInfo.Version
    $objInfo | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Host -Value $vmhost
    $objInfo | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DriverName -Value $driverName
    $objInfo | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name FirmwareVersion -Value $fwversion
    $objInfo | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DriverVersion -Value $drversion
    $nicinfo += $objInfo
}

$nicinfo
```

When I type this into my PowerCLI console, this displays like I want, without an issue.  Ex:

```
    Host    DriverName                            FirmwareVersion                      DriverVersion
    ----    ----------                            ---------------                      -------------
    host01  elxnet                                10.2.377.29                          10.4.255.13
    host02  elxnet                                10.2.377.29                          10.4.255.13
    host03  be2net                                4.6.281.8                            4.6.142.10
    host04  be2net                                4.6.281.8                            4.6.142.10
```

However, my challenge lies when I attempt to run this same code inside a PowerShell script (.ps1 file.)  I get the output as a list, not a nicely formatted table.

```
Host            : host01
DriverName      : elxnet
FirmwareVersion : 10.2.377.29
DriverVersion   : 10.4.255.13


Host            : host02
DriverName      : elxnet
FirmwareVersion : 10.2.377.29
DriverVersion   : 10.4.255.13


Host            : host03
DriverName      : be2net
FirmwareVersion : 4.6.281.8
DriverVersion   : 4.6.142.10


Host            : host04
DriverName      : be2net
FirmwareVersion : 4.6.281.8
DriverVersion   : 4.6.142.10
```

I like the first output and would like to see that as the output when I run this code inside a script - it makes for a much easier 'at a glance' way of seeing the outdated drivers/firmware.  Not to mention when you have 30+ hosts, the first output means I do not need to scroll through to look at everything at once.

Comment: When you are running your script what is the  result of this line `$FormatEnumerationLimit`? Is it less then 4? That is the preference variable that governs PowerShell outputting objects as tables vs lists. You can set it temporarily during script execution to -1 then restore it to it original value a tthe end of the script.

Comment: The value was exactly 4.  I changed it to -1 or 20, but it didn't seem to affect the output any.

Comment: Interesting. Just so I can test what is your PowerShell version for the failed execution.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this issue at this time. Can you include how you call the script to display the data? Or is it just `C:\temp> .\test.ps1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was indeed something simple.

Instead of having this solely at the end of the script:

```
$nicinfo
```

I modified it as such:

```
Out-Host -InputObject $nicinfo
```

Comment: This means I have to do any formatting of my object before I output it, kind of a hassle but it gets me the output I want.

Answer (score 0):

Use Format-Table (or its alias FT) to format the output as a table.
for example yourscript.ps1 | ft

Comment: That gives me the same undesired list output as above.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you change your last line from

```
$nicinfo
```

to

```
$nicinfo | ft
```

Comment: If I do so within the script:  

out-lineoutput : The object of type "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData" is not valid or not in the correct sequence. This
 is likely caused by a user-specified "format-table" command which is conflicting with the default formatting.

Comment: If I do so outside the script, I get the same output.